# Mpandroidchart fail to group data as desired?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to group the data coming form Rest Api as monthly basis like Jan, Feb, Mar..., but it doesn't plotting or grouping the value like I desired.

**Now Where did I go wrong?**

Or should I follow another approach?

If I have to then what is it?

**Here is my code:**

```
private void graphData(Response<List<MontlyPatientAnalysisModel>> response) {

            List<BarEntry> entriesJan = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesFeb = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesMar = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesApr = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesMay = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesJun = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesJuly = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesAug = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesSep = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesOct = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesNov = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesDec = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entriesTotal = new ArrayList<>();

            final List<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();

            if (response.body() != null) {
                for (MontlyPatientAnalysisModel montlyPatientAnalysisModel : response.body()) {

                    entriesJan.add(new BarEntry(1, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getJan(), "January"));
                    entriesFeb.add(new BarEntry(2, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getFeb(), "February"));
                    entriesMar.add(new BarEntry(3, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getMar(),"March"));
                    entriesApr.add(new BarEntry(4, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getApr(), "April"));
                    entriesMay.add(new BarEntry(5, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getMay(), "May"));
                    entriesJun.add(new BarEntry(6, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getJun(), "Jun"));
                    entriesJuly.add(new BarEntry(7, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getJul(), "July"));
                    entriesAug.add(new BarEntry(8, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getAug(), "August"));
                    entriesSep.add(new BarEntry(9, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getSep(), "September"));
                    entriesOct.add(new BarEntry(10, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getOct(), "October"));
                    entriesNov.add(new BarEntry(11, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getNov(), "November"));
                    entriesDec.add(new BarEntry(12, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getDec(), "December"));
                    entriesTotal.add(new BarEntry(13, montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getTotal(), "Total"));

                    xLabel.add(montlyPatientAnalysisModel.getName());

                }
            }

            BarDataSet barDataSetJan, barDataSetFeb, barDataSetMar,
                    barDataSetApr, barDataSetMay, barDataSetJun, barDataSetJuly,
                    barDataSetAug, barDataSetSep, barDataSetOct, barDataSetNov, barDataSetDec, barDataSetTotal;

            barDataSetJan = new BarDataSet(entriesJan, "Jan");
            barDataSetJan.setColor(randomAndroidColor1);
            barDataSetJan.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor1);
            barDataSetJan.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetFeb = new BarDataSet(entriesFeb, "Feb");
            barDataSetFeb.setColor(randomAndroidColor2);
            barDataSetFeb.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor2);
            barDataSetFeb.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetMar = new BarDataSet(entriesMar, "Mar");
            barDataSetMar.setColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetMar.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetMar.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetApr = new BarDataSet(entriesApr, "Apr");
            barDataSetApr.setColor(randomAndroidColor4);
            barDataSetApr.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor4);
            barDataSetApr.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetMay = new BarDataSet(entriesMay, "May");
            barDataSetMay.setColor(randomAndroidColor5);
            barDataSetMay.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor5);
            barDataSetMay.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetJun = new BarDataSet(entriesJun, "Jun");
            barDataSetJun.setColor(randomAndroidColor6);
            barDataSetJun.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor6);
            barDataSetJun.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetJuly = new BarDataSet(entriesJuly, "July");
            barDataSetJuly.setColor(randomAndroidColor1);
            barDataSetJuly.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor1);
            barDataSetJuly.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetAug = new BarDataSet(entriesAug, "Aug");
            barDataSetAug.setColor(randomAndroidColor2);
            barDataSetAug.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor2);
            barDataSetAug.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetSep = new BarDataSet(entriesSep, "Sep");
            barDataSetSep.setColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetSep.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetSep.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetOct = new BarDataSet(entriesOct, "Oct");
            barDataSetOct.setColor(randomAndroidColor4);
            barDataSetOct.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor4);
            barDataSetOct.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetNov = new BarDataSet(entriesNov, "Nov");
            barDataSetNov.setColor(randomAndroidColor5);
            barDataSetNov.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor5);
            barDataSetNov.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetDec = new BarDataSet(entriesDec, "Dec");
            barDataSetDec.setColor(randomAndroidColor6);
            barDataSetDec.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor6);
            barDataSetDec.setValueTextSize(5f);

            barDataSetTotal = new BarDataSet(entriesTotal, "Total");
            barDataSetTotal.setColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetTotal.setValueTextColor(randomAndroidColor3);
            barDataSetTotal.setValueTextSize(5f);

            //add the data
            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> barDataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetJan);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetFeb);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetMar);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetApr);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetMay);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetJun);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetJuly);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetAug);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetSep);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetOct);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetNov);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetDec);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSetTotal);

            BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSets);
            mBarChart.setData(barData);
            //barData.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
            Description description = new Description();
            description.setText("Growth rate per month");
            description.setTextSize(12);
            mBarChart.setDescription(description);

            final XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setLabelCount(entriesJan.size());
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xLabel) {
                @Override
                public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                    if (value >= 0) {
                        if (value <= xLabel.size() - 1) {
                            return xLabel.get((int) value);
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            });
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            xAxis.setGranularity(1);
            //xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
            xAxis.setTextSize(9);
            xAxis.setTextColor(R.color.colorBlack);
            xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-13);
            mBarChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

            YAxis leftAxis = mBarChart.getAxisLeft();
            mBarChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(3000, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            leftAxis.setTextSize(12);
            leftAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
            leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
            leftAxis.setGranularity(1);
            leftAxis.setLabelCount(12, true);

            mBarChart.animateY(1000);
            mBarChart.setDragEnabled(true);
            mBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(15);

            float groupSpace = 0.060f;
            float barSpace = 0.011f;
            barData.setBarWidth((1 - groupSpace) / barDataSets.size() - barSpace);
            mBarChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
            mBarChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + mBarChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * 18);
            mBarChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
            mBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
            mBarChart.groupBars(0f, groupSpace, barSpace);
            mBarChart.fitScreen();
            mBarChart.zoom(4.5f, 1.2f, 0, 0);

            barData.setDrawValues(true);
            barData.notifyDataChanged();
            mBarChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mBarChart.invalidate();
            mBarChart.refreshDrawableState();
        }
```

**Any idea guys where did I go wrong?**

**Should I follow another approach?**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample

Check this link, While if you are creating group chart your groupspace , barWidth is more important , in my example.

```
    float barWidth = 0.25f;
    float barSpace = 0.05f;
    float groupSpace = 0.40f;

    barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    barChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDescription(null);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    barChart.setFitBars(true);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

           BarDataSet set1, set2;

            set1 = new BarDataSet(mViewModel.getBalList(), "Remaining");
            set1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.darkRed));
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setDrawValues(false);
            set2 = new BarDataSet(mViewModel.getCollectedList(), "Collected");
            set2.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.primaryYellow));
            set2.setDrawIcons(false);
            set2.setDrawValues(false)
            BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
            barChart.setData(data);
            data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
            barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
            barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0f);
            barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(mViewModel.getxVals().size());
            barChart.groupBars(0f, groupSpace, barSpace);
            //   barChartView.setFitBars(true)
            barChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(true);
            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
            xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
            xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
            xAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));

            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(mViewModel.getxVals()));
            binding.className.setText(mViewModel.getxVals().get(0));
            xAxis.setLabelCount(mViewModel.getxVals().size());
            xAxis.mAxisMaximum = mViewModel.getxVals().size();
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
            xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
            xAxis.setSpaceMin(4f);
            xAxis.setSpaceMax(4f);

            YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
            leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
            leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
            leftAxis.setSpaceTop(1f);
            leftAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
            leftAxis.setTextSize(10f);
            leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
            barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            barChart.setVisibleXRange(1f, 4.5f);
            barChart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
            barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);

            Legend legend = barChart.getLegend();
            legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
            legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
            legend.setDrawInside(false);

            barChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Didn't solve my problem? Do you understand my problem? Thank you